# About Python's inner to outer evaluation order in generator expressions

Tags: python, generator, operator-precedence

When iterating over the following generator expression,

```
fun(i) for i in mylist if i not in setA.union(setB)
```

is the `setA.union` method called in each iteration, or only once?

Comment: It is called `len(mylist)` times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple proof using `dis` module:

```
In [24]: def func():
   ....:     a=set([1,2,3])
   ....:     b=set([3,4,5])
   ....:     c=[i for i in xrange(10) if i in a.union(b)]
   ....:     

In [25]: dis.dis(func)

  4          42 BUILD_LIST               0
             45 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (xrange)
             48 LOAD_CONST               6 (10)
             51 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             54 GET_ITER                          #iterator returned from xrange

        >>   55 FOR_ITER                33 (to 91) #until the iterator is not exhausted
             58 STORE_FAST               2 (i)
             61 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             64 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             67 LOAD_ATTR                2 (union)
             70 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             73 CALL_FUNCTION            1      #union() is being called in each iteration
             76 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             79 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       55
             82 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             85 LIST_APPEND              2
             88 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           55
                                                         #end of loop    
        >>   91 STORE_FAST               3 (c)
             94 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             97 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, for your example it is going to be called in each iteration i.e. `len(mylist)` times.

Comment: For these cases, I rely on `cProfile`, as its more explicit

Answer (score 3):

yes, `setA.union(setB)` is called every time in the iteration,

you should do this before the generator expression and store it in a variable

```
setvalues = setA.union(setB)

fun(i) for i in mylist if i not in setvalues
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of validating it, is to profile it. Borrowing the example from @AshwiniChaudhary, I will run it through cProfile

```
>>> def func():
     a=set([1,2,3])
     b=set([3,4,5])
     c=[i for i in xrange(10) if i in a.union(b)]


>>> import cProfile
>>> cProfile.run("func()")
         13 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <pyshell#1045>:1(func)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'union' of 'set' objects}
```

Here it clearly mentions, that the union is called `10` times

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I use it a lot to profile my code. Though sometimes the results could be misleading